# Issue on String to Int conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, type-conversion

I need to convert a String to Int and i can't find a solution since i have an issue that is presenting only on one machine, while on the others 2 it works good.

[image]

As seen from the screenshot, String value `"2778"` is converted to Int `2778` but when i continue in debug mode, `my_id_int` variable is equal to `0x00000ada` and Session variable too obviously. I've already tried using `Int.Parse` method or use directly Int value on `ASPxGridView` column without success, while on the other machines it works always good. Maybe there is a particular setting on Visual Studio or something similar.

**Update**

This is not only a visual issue, when i retrieve Session value on another page i need to run a query using int value but it doesn't work as expected.

```
int my_id = (Int32)Session[SESSION_ID_INTERNO_KEY];
// valorized as 0x00000b09

string sql = " select * from table where id = @my_id ";
...
```

Comment: `0x00000ada` is hexadecimal for `2778`, so the program works correctly.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: '0xada' is 2778. It's just the debugger showing it in hexadecimal form. The debugger is just formatting the number like that during display, but it has the same value. If you don't like the debugger showing things in hex, then turn it off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck Hexadecimal Display in debug mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i can't understand why it works now. This is only a display option and shouldn't modify program behaviour. If i disable Hexadecimal display, i can see the int value and my query retrieve data correctly! While if i activate hexadecimal display model it doesn't :/